# Error message is given when creating a CSV from a List of Lists which are based on a Datamodel

Tags: c#, list, linq, csv

**Background**

Currently executing a stored procedures on a database using [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), the result is each call will give me a list of OfficeGroup,OfficeGroupID, which is subsequently bound to a data model.

**Problem**

I am having trouble trying to create this CSV file, I can opun a great [StackOverflowExample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339922/c-sharp-how-to-write-a-listliststring-to-csv-file) example which I have started to use.  The only difference is that I have a list of objects and not strings.  So I am trying to alter that code to my needs but I am getting the following error.

**Error**

`Error  CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'TestScript.Models.MarketStoredProcedureDatamodel`

**DataModel**

```
namespace TestScript.Models
{
  public class MarketStoredProcedureDatamodel
  {
    public string OfficeGroupID { get; set; }
    public string OfficeGroup { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
List<List<MarketStoredProcedureDatamodel>> storedProcCollection = new List<List<MarketStoredProcedureDatamodel>>();
const char SEPARATOR = ',';
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
{
  storedProcCollection.ForEach(line =>
  {
     var lineArray = line.Select(c =>
            ERROR Line >> c.OfficeGroup.Contains(SEPARATOR) ? c.OfficeGroupID.Replace(SEPARATOR.ToString(), "\\" + SEPARATOR) : c).ToArray();
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPARATOR, lineArray));
       });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is that you want to return c.OfficeGroup here (scroll to the right to see the code on the end):

```
c.OfficeGroup.Contains(SEPARATOR) ? c.OfficeGroupID.Replace(SEPARATOR.ToString(), "\\" + SEPARATOR) : c)
```

Use this instead:

```
c.OfficeGroup.Contains(SEPARATOR) ? c.OfficeGroupID.Replace(SEPARATOR.ToString(), "\\" + SEPARATOR) : c.OfficeGroup)
```

Your code is returning the MarketStoredProcedureDatamodel object instead of the OfficeGroup that you want to get for your CSV.

Comment: Thanks! Please select this as the answer.